# Schedule Jenkin builds with custom parameter using a config file from SVN?

Tags: jenkins

As the title suggests, is there anyway for me to schedule jenkins builds with custom parameters, using a JSON or HTML, or any kind of file that I can just push to my SVN/Git and Jenkin will pull/check periodically and build as scheduled?

I want to format the builds with something like this:

```
{
  time:[
    year: 2022
    month: 7
    date: 20
    hour: 06
    min: 00
  ]
  BuildNumber: 1
  BuildParams: {
    UPDATE: 1
    VERSION: 1000a
    BUILD_TYPE: Beta
  }
}
```

The time can be in x days instead of exact date. And the build params (UPDATE, VERSION, BUILD_TYPE...) are exact build params of the current pipeline script.

It would be best if the config file can be pulled from git or SVN but even it's a local jenkins setting it's still a huge improvement compared to before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you want these as Jenkins parameters, instead of having your build script read the config file directly? For example, if you want to rename the compiled file with a version number, this would be very straightforward to do in a batch script.

Comment: Or do you want to configure what jobs will be built and when? Is there some reason you cannot configure the schedule in the Jenkins UI, do you expect the schedule will change often?

Comment: The main reason is because our current project are handled among various studios, and we share a number of scripts among them.  Also the builds are distributed among various build machines which info and configs I don't want to commit to the SVN.

Comment: The idea of letting the build script reading the file directly was considered but it would be the second resort if I cannot make it work with the Jenkins configs.